# index correct function and has correct values although it prints me garbage?

Tags: c++, c++14

I don't really know the issue. the index are correct yet gives me garbage memory

So I wanted to implement Init lists for my array class. and it correctly sets the values but not it does work for somereason when printing like i used a debugger and it told me the values are set.

```
#include "headers/array.hpp"

int main() {
    Array<int,3> My = { 5,2,3};
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < My.size();  i++) {
        std::cout << My[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

array.hpp

```
#pragma once

class Array {
public:
    using u_size_t = signed long long;
    using s_size_t = unsigned long long;
    Array(std::initializer_list<T> InitializerList) {
        u_size_t i = 0;
        for (const auto& Element : InitializerList) {
            m_Data[i] = Element;
            i++;
        }
    }
    class Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator(T* ptr)
                :m_Ptr(ptr)
        {

        }
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) {
            return this->m_Ptr != other.m_Ptr;
        }
        bool operator==(const Iterator& other) {
            return this->m_Ptr == other.m_Ptr;
        }
        T* operator++() {
            return ++m_Ptr;
        }
        T* operator++(int) {
            T* temp = m_Ptr;
            m_Ptr++;
            return temp;
        }
        T& operator*() {
            return *m_Ptr;
        }
        T& operator->(){
            return m_Ptr;
        }
    private:
       mutable T* m_Ptr;
    };
    constexpr size_t size() const { return Size; }
    Iterator begin() { return &m_Data[0]; }
    Iterator end() { return &m_Data[Size]; }
    
    Iterator begin() const { return &m_Data[0]; }
    Iterator end() const { return &m_Data[Size]; }


    T& operator[](s_size_t index) {
        return m_Data [
            index = index > -1 ? index : Size + index
        ];
    }
    const T& operator[](s_size_t index) const {
        return m_Data[
            index = index > -1 ? index : Size + index
        ];
    }
private:
    mutable T m_Data[Size];
};
```

when using V Studio debugger to inspect the values everything is correct yet still gives me garbage?? I don't really know what to do and it is frustrating. Weirdly enough using the Iterator makes it not print garbage. but i really can't daigonuse the issue,

Comment: `using s_size_t = unsigned long long;` - are you really sure about that? Calling your unsigned index type `s_size_t` is very confusing (and quite likely a cause of your problems)

Comment: This code doesn't compile. It is missing a template declaration, it is missing the member "Size" and there are probably more issues once these have been corrected.

Comment: Why is the unsigned type prefixed with an `s`, and the signed type prefixed with a `u`?

Comment: `index = index > -1 ? index : Size + index` is parsed as `(index = (index > -1) ) ? index : Size + index`. So, first `index` is assigned the value `1` (`true` converted to integer). Then, the condition is determined to be true, and `m_Data[Size + index]` is accessed. Whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: there is no member called size.it is a template arguement.

Comment: I didn't relize i made that silly mistake prefixing the wrong letter and it fixed the issue wow i feel so stupid.